# Change in MIMI Type definitions?

Tags: php, mime-types

I used to get different MIMI types when using finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE).

For instance, based on memory, I believe docx were application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document (see this StackOverflow post [What is a correct mime type for docx, pptx etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212861/what-is-a-correct-mime-type-for-docx-pptx-etc)).  I also recall them showing as application/zip, but that might have been when using mime_content_type().  Also, thought js files came up as application/x-javascript.

Below is what I am now getting along with the script to display them.  I recently updated to PHP 5.14, and wonder if there is a new standard or whether I messed something up.  I am fine with this, but will have to change my scripts which compared extensions to MIMI types.

EDIT - Just found the following on the PHP manual.

> As of PHP >= 5.3.11 and >= 5.4.1 the magic datababase format has
>   changed. Due to this, the internal mime database was upgraded. This
>   affects especially the code where external magic is read in. Reading
>   in magic files of the older formats will not work. Also, some textual
>   representations of the mime types has changed, for instance for PHP
>   would be "PHP script, ASCII text" instead of "PHP script text"
>   returned.

Thank you

MIMI List based on below script

```
- directory
csv - text/plain
doc - application/msword
docx - application/msword
htm - text/html
ini - text/plain
jpg - image/jpeg
js - text/plain
mp3 - application/octet-stream
pdf - application/pdf
php - text/html
pptx - application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
pst - application/octet-stream
so - application/x-sharedlib
txt - text/plain
wmv - video/x-ms-asf
xls - application/msword
xlsx - application/vnd.ms-excel
zip - application/zip
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // return mime type ala mimetype extension
foreach (glob("*") as $filename) {
    $files[pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)]=array('filename'=>$filename,'finfo'=>finfo_file($finfo, $filename));
}
ksort($files);
foreach ($files as $fileext=>$file) {
    echo ($fileext.' - '.$file['finfo'].'<br />');
}
finfo_close($finfo);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mime types printed will differ based on the system's configuration. If the system is configured to open .docx files in MSWord, then it'll have `application/msword` as the mime type. Likewise, if the same extension .docx is configured to open in LibreOffice, it'll have `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` as the mime type.

Because of this dependency on the server's configuration, mime types are not very reliable.

Comment: What is the most common configuration?  Is there a better way to ensure that an uploaded file's extension matches the file type?